# Using NetBeans and Command Line Arguments

Tags: java, netbeans

I am new to java and I know this isn't for homework but I need help. I've typed a program in java and I need to have the values passed in the command line arguments and that is where I am getting stuck I quite understand how to do that. Here is the question that I needed to answer.

(Write an application that uses an enhanced for a statement to sum the double values passed by the command-line arguments. [Hint: Use the static method parseDouble of class Double to convert a String to a double value .])

here is my code

```
public class Enhanced {

   public static void main(String[] args) {

   Double total = 0.0;
   for (String number : args) {

   total += Double.parseDouble(number);
   }
   //print total
   System.out.printf("Total of array elements: %f%n", total);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First thing you would need to compile your code using below command.

```
javac Enhanced.java
```

It will compile your program and prepare a class file for it, then you need to run that class as specified in other answers.

```
java Enhanced 3.2 2.12 5.83
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's how to specify command-line arguments when running your app under NetBeans:

1. Under your **Projects** tab, right-click on your project and choose **Properties**
2. In the Project Properties dialog, under **Categories**, select **Run**;
3. Enter your command-line arguments in the **Arguments** field;
4. Click **OK**;

The arguments you entered will be used every time you run the project after that.

Comment: Thank you so much I found what I was doing wrong I was right-clicking and running the program that way when all I needed to do was press the green play button. I appreciate that help thanks again.